# How can we convert a string to a user defined object in java

Tags: java, casting, type-conversion

I have created a string  and now I need to convert it into a user defined object. so how it can be done .for eg the `String data=" Help me"`.
so this string has to be converted to the object so it can be passed for the given function.
as i need to pass the object for a function 
`public abstract void add(Treecreat item)`;

Comment: Not sure that it is the answer, but google for json and json-deserializer libraries, for example google gson.

Comment: What type of String? Can you provide sample?

Comment: The question's too broad as it stands - could you provide source code for the object you want to convert to?

Comment: Who mentioned JSON? Please add an example of the string and the object. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: can you please elaborate your question tell me what is the string you are generating and what are the properties you want to take out of that string

Comment: What do you mean by "user defined object"?

Comment: technically the String is already an Object, so you are done

Comment: What is a `Treecreat` object? Does it have properties that can be set?

Comment: yes Treecreat object has properties that can be set  @user32116

Comment: @vinodraj Then you can set the property of `Treecreat` that needs the value of `data`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to transfer a String into a `Treecreat`? You should give `Treecreat` a constructor like this.

```
public Treecreat(String yourString){
    this.myString = yourString;
}
```

So the String is in `Treecreat` and you can work with it in your method, with call the method in this way: `add(new Treecreat(data)`.